# Flag question as off-topic, limited other stack exchange options

Tags: discussion, feature-request, scope

I flagged a question as off-topic; it was a stats plotting question, so I wanted to send it over to Cross Validated. However, the only choices it displayed were LaTeX and Stack Overflow, so I went back a step and changed my flag to "blatantly" off-topic.

I like having the most common misclassified exchanges at the top, but shouldn't I be able to send it (or flag it for transfer) to any other Stack Exchange site?